# Designing a layout like android home screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I needed to design an layout which looks like android home screen as attached in this post.

[image: layout like android home screen]

Tried but could not get any example for above layout, tried writing with Linear Layouts with weights but could not get so many ImageButtons or Buttons in one screen I am designing on Froyo and the screen should be scrollable.

Any example would be helpful.

thanks.

Comment: use gridview for the above layout

Comment: you can use absolute layout. But its not a good practice to do that!

Comment: yes you should use grid view to acheive this . tuto example : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/                  2- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/

Comment: thanks but clicking on each grid should take me to different activities.

Comment: you can set a click listner on grid view

Comment: @jnr can we drag different images in and around of the grid view. button one should be dragged and placed in place of button 6, button 6 should be in place of button 1 now is it possible and how can I set an id and getting id I can start an activity

Comment: @Mukunda, He just want to design the layout. he doesn't mention drag the images around the layout. he just need `design`. only `design` please read the question carefully

Comment: you can set a gridview adapter like in listview , so you should some search on that and create your aowen adapter

Comment: @jnr thanks, Ram Kiran I forgot to add that the buttons should also be draggable and placed in a new position.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this type of layout by using grid layout . [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) is the example how to set images in grid Layout

Comment: Ram kiran thanks but on clicking on each grid it hould take to different activities.

Comment: ya you should maintain the array of type Activity[] for all activities.

Comment: examples any, can we drag different images in and around of the grid view. button one should be dragged and placed in place of button 6, button 6 should be in place of button 1 now is it possible and how can I set an id and getting id I can start an activity.

Comment: thanks I forgot to add that the buttons should also be draggable and placed in a new position.